# Qt async call: how to run something after an async call has finished its job

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous

I have code like below which does an async call:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "endSelectionHandling", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

I want to modify the code like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "endSelectionHandling", Qt::QueuedConnection);

// I want to add statements here which depend on the result of the above async call.
// How can I wait for the above async call to finish its jobs?
```

How can I wait for Qt asycn call to finish its job? Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you want to wait right after the function call then why don't you call it directly i.e. blocking call? That would be the perfect solution in your case unless there's something in between that you want to do.

Comment: @Azeem Actually there is more code in between. The original code is written by someone else who is not accessible. Doing the direct blocking call breaks somethings in the application.

Comment: Right. Please take a look at my answer and example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, it looks like you don't need an asynchronous call at all because you are waiting for the result right after making it an async call.

But, in case you have some code in between, you may use C++11's [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to call the function asynchronously and then wait on its [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) whenever and wherever you need its result after doing other stuff.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define LOG()    std::cout << __func__ << " : "

void test()
{
    LOG() << "IN\n";

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 1s );

    LOG() << "OUT\n";
}

int main()
{
    LOG() << "Calling test()...\n";

    auto f = std::async( std::launch::async, test );

    LOG() << "Running test()...\n";

    // ...                             ...
    // ... You can do other stuff here ...
    // ...                             ...

    f.wait(); // Blocking call to wait for the result to be available

    LOG() << "Exiting...\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
main : Calling test()...
main : Running test()...
test : IN
test : OUT
main : Exiting...
```

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/OviYU6

**UPDATE**:

However, in Qt realm, you may want to use [`QtConcurrent::run`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) and [`QFuture`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) to do things in Qt way.

Here's the example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QThread>

#define LOG()    qDebug() << __func__ << ": "

void test()
{
    LOG() << "IN";

    QThread::sleep( 1 );

    LOG() << "OUT";
}

int main()
{
    LOG() << "Calling test()...";

    auto f = QtConcurrent::run( test );

    LOG() << "Running test()...";

    // ...                             ...
    // ... You can do other stuff here ...
    // ...                             ...

    f.waitForFinished(); // Blocking call to wait for function to finish

    LOG() << "Exiting...";

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
main : Calling test()...
main : Running test()...
test : IN
test : OUT
main : Exiting...
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'm going to test this approach.

Comment: @user3405291: You are welcome! Sure, check this out and kindly accept if it answers your question.